# find function on array with dictionary names not working while finding username

Tags: arrays, node.js, find, passport.js

I'm trying to find a username for a passport callback.

I've currently have used the array and a .find() function but keep getting an error.

```js
const u = { uhteddy:
   { id: '1565590076979',
     username: 'uhTeddy',
     verified: false,
     password: "" 
} }

const initializePassport = require('../passport-config.js');
initializePassport(passport, 
    username => u.find(user => user[username] === username),
    id => db.get('users').find(user => user.id === id)
);
```

I'm expecting no errors with a .find so that the authorization will go through

> **Error:** (node:74036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: u.find is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Becasue `u` is not an `Array` it's a `Plain Object`.

In case of `Array.find` you can easyli just lookup from the object:

```
username => u[username]
```